# Disable right click without JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to turn off the right click button on mouse by NOT using JavaScript?

Comment: This may have been asked a few times before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=disable+right+click

Comment: If you think carefully, disabling right click makes as little sense as disabling middle click. In most browsers, all right click does is displaying a context menu and most of its functionality can be accomplished through other menus or keyboard shortcuts. Perhaps what you actually want to disable is certain browser feature :-?

Comment: Yes, you have to get a screwdriver and prise it off the mouse.

Comment: @Tom — that would probably just expose the microswitch, which might still be clickable. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you mean "by a webpage", then no.

Comment: +1 Sometimes getting over the minimum character limit must be a chore. :-)

Comment: @abrabar: why do you want to disable right click anyway?  **Everything** is still accessible without it, including images and source code, you're just annoying people with a legitimate use for the context menu by disabling it.

Comment: yeah, i know, but my employer want it in this way )

Answer (score 1):

No.

What is your objective?  If it is to protect images, you are just going to annoy your users, and you need to realise that anything on the web *can always be copied*.

There are really very few genuine requirments, if any, to disable the right click button on a website.  Think about the consequences, and your reasons before taking away from basic user functionality that all users will expect to have.

Answer (score 0):

If the specific page is just to present a document and does not need to be interacted with, there is a workaround, which does not disable the context menu (to cast or translate etc.). It involves making a mistake that loads a broken element over the entire width and height. Something like this will do-

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
Your browser doesn't support iframes
```

PS: The obvious downside is that it gives an error in the console. (in this case it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'). Plus it has very limited use case.

PSS: If JS can be used, [canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_filltext/) may offer better protection.

Answer (score -1):

Add `oncontextmenu="return false;"` attribute in the `<body>`

But again it can be bypassed easily, sorry there's no method to completely disallow people from copying your content. The better way than using these codes would be displaying a notice saying "DON'T COPY THE CONTENT" and hope people obey it.

Comment: The question says "without JavaScript"